# Angular 6 CLI localisation & Internationalization for multilingual support

Tags: angular, typescript, localization, internationalization, angular6

We are using Angular 6 in our Application. In that application we want to give multilingual support.

How can we implement localisation & Internationalization in angular 6? Its an angular 6 version.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Refer: https://dgwebidea.blogspot.com/2020/01/angular-internationalization-and.html

**Translate Angular 6 apps with ngx-translate
What we will do:**

Create minimal Angular6 project
Install and load ngx-translate
Init the TranslateService
Create .json translation files
Translate simple title and intro
Integrate language switcher
Translate sentence with variable

### Using nested .json objects

**Create minimal Angular6 project**

We use @angular/cli to create a new project named “traduction” in the terminal:

```
ng new traduction --prefix tr
cd traduction
ng serve -o
```

---

**Install and load ngx-translate**

Use npm in your terminal within the project folder “traduction”:

```
npm install @ngx-translate/core --save
npm install @ngx-translate/http-loader
```

> Note:
>   Use following versions forbelow angular 6

```
"@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1" 
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1"
```

> and for angular 5 use latest version 10 and above

**Import the necessary modules into app.module.ts :**

```
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
```

Add a function, that returns a “TranslateHttpLoader” and export it (needed by AoT). In this case the HttpLoaderFactory function we create, returns a Object that can load Translations using Http and .json, but you could write your own Class that for example uses a global JavaScript variable instead of loading a file, or that uses Google Translate:

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

OR

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

We then need to import our modules into the @NgModule, this is the import that tells Angular to load this Module into your AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**Inject the TranslateService**

In “app.component.ts” we now init the “TranslateService”, we import the TranslateService:

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
```

Then inside the AppComponent Class we inject the service and define our default language. And to be ready for the next step, we add a function to switch the language.

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
  }

  switchLanguage(language: string) {
    this.translate.use(language);
  }
```

**Create .json translation files**

We now create our translation files inside the assets/i18n folder:

```
src/assets/i18n/en.json

{
    "Title": "Translation example",
    "Intro": "Hello I am Arthur, I am 42 years old."
}

src/assets/i18n/fr.json

{
    "Title": "Exemple de traduction",
    "Intro": "Bonjour je m'appelle Arthur, j'ai 42 ans."
}
```

These are simple .json files that will be loaded by our “TranslateHttpLoader” we created in “app.module.ts”.

**Translate simple title and intro**

In app.component.html we add a header with the translate “directive” inside the “h1” tag. This directive will take the text inside the tag and replace it with the matching translation. If you use the directive you have to make sure, that there is nothing else inside the tag but the text.

As a second example we use the “TranslationPipe” to translate a label with define as a inline string. As we sometimes have value inside a translation that we want to replace, we can pass a data object into the “translate” pipe.

```
<h1 translate>Title</h1>

<div>
  {{ 'Intro' | translate:user }}
</div>
```

**Integrate language switcher**

We can now attach our language switcher function that we saw above in app.component.ts to a button. In this case we create a button for each language and call the switchLanguage() function with the matching language key.

```
<button (click)="switchLanguage('en')">en</button>

<button (click)="switchLanguage('fr')">fr</button>
```

**Translate sentence with variable**

As mentioned before, you sometimes have sentences to that contain variable. In this little example we have a user object with age and name inside the “app.component.ts”, and we want to translate a sentence that will contain this values:

```
...
export class AppComponent {
  user = {
    name: 'Arthur',
    age: 42
  };
...
}
```

Because we pass this object into the “translate” pipe, we can now use it’s properties in our translation with the {{ placeholder }} notation.

```
src/assets/i18n/en.json

{
    "Title": "Translation example",
    "Intro": "Hello I am {{name}}, I am {{age}} years old."
}

src/assets/i18n/fr.json

{
    "Title": "Exemple de traduction",
    "Intro": "Bonjour je m'appelle {{name}}, j'ai {{age}} ans."
}
```

**Using nested .json objects**

If you want to be able to have more control on your translation, and for example translate page blocks (from the end-user perspective) or components (from the developer perspective), one solution could be the following; use nested .json objects as described in the git repo. An example could look like this in the -json files:

```
{
    "Title": "Translation example",
    "Intro": "Hello I am {{name}}, I am {{age}} years old.",
    "Startpage": {
        "TranslationSections": "Hello World"
    },
     "Aboutpage": {
        "TranslationSections": "We are letsboot"
    }
}


{
    "Title": "Exemple de traduction",
    "Intro": "Bonjour je m'appelle {{name}}, j'ai {{age}} ans.",
    "Startpage": {
        "TranslationSections": "Bonjour Monde"
    },
    "Aboutpage": {
        "TranslationSections": "Nous sommes letsboot"
    }
}
```

**And in the corresponding template:**

```
<h1 translate>Title</h1>

<div>
  {{ 'Intro' | translate:user }}
</div>

<div>
  {{ 'Startpage.TranslationSections' | translate }}
</div>

<div>
  {{ 'Aboutpage.TranslationSections' | translate }}
</div>

<br/>

<button (click)="switchLanguage('en')">en</button>
<button (click)="switchLanguage('fr')">fr</button>
```

Comment: How could I do if I want to use by default locale?

Comment: @JesusSandrea use browser language

Comment: var language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
alert(language); //works IE/SAFARI/CHROME/FF

Comment: in build it gives 404

Comment: check file locations for build

Comment: It works fine in app.component.html , I am unable to use  it in other parts of the app  like 
<div>
  {{ 'hello' | translate}}
</div>  I get the following error  The pipe 'translate' could not be found

Comment: @DineshGhule It works fine in app.component.html , I am unable to use it in other parts of the app like <div> {{ 'hello' | translate}} </div> I get the following error The pipe 'translate' could not be found. I have created a service file and put the constructor code in their after that how should we do that?

Comment: @DDD which version you are using for angular?

Comment: @DineshGhule v6.0.1

Comment: @DDD which version you using for @ngx-translate/core & @ngx-translate/http-loader ? check your package.json

Comment: @DineshGhule `"@ngx-translate/core": "9.1.1",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "2.0.1",`

Comment: @DineshGhule using `"@angular/core": "5.2.2"` not 6

Comment: @DDD try with "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1" 
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1"

Comment: @DineshGhule not working get this error in console `Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[rootTextManager -> TranslateService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[rootTextManager -> TranslateService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for TranslateService!`

Comment: @DDD add service in the app.module and import

Comment: I have added `RootTextManager` into appmodule's providers. Still getting same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206407/discussion-between-ddd-and-dinesh-ghule).

Answer (score 0):

**component.module.ts**

```
export function translateHttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: translateHttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
```

**class LanguagService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService, LangChangeEvent } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class LanguageService {
    language$ = new ReplaySubject<LangChangeEvent>(1);
    translate = this.translateService;
    // 國旗對照;

    constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {}

    setInitState() {
      this.translateService.addLangs(['en', 'cn','vi']);
      console.log( 'Browser Lang', this.translate.getBrowserLang());
      const browserLang = (this.translate.getBrowserLang().includes('vi')) ? 'vi' : 'cn'  ;
      console.log("anhtt "," anguage  = " +browserLang);

      this.setLang(browserLang);
    }

    setLang(lang: string) {
      this.translateService.onLangChange.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(result => {
        this.language$.next(result);
      });
      this.translateService.use(lang);

    }
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>How to multi language in angular 7</h1>
<p >{{'content' |translate}}</p>
<h4 translate>
  {{'message' |translate}}
</h4>
<button (click)="selectLanguageEN()">English</button>
<button (click)="selectLanguageCN()">中國</button>
<button (click)="selectLanguageVI()">Viet Nam</button>
```

**Code demo:**

https://tienanhvn.blogspot.com/2019/06/angular-7-how-to-multi-language.html